# How to return JSON data similar to the way XML returns data from database asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

I am really new to asp.net and angular.js also. I have followed a course on lynda.com regarding asp.net 4.5. In the course we learn how to use asp.net api,but in the course we use ajax to get data back as JSON and format it before binding it to the page. I want to use angular.js to display this data from the database. I just want an easy example so I can start playing with angular more using the data that is returned. Here's the html...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ApiClient.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExploreCalifornia.API.ApiClient" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Explore California Tours</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCon">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="tours">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in tours">
            <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.Rating }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>


    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/myCon.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

now the angular controller...

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCon', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/tour").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.Tours = data.Tour;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.title = "Oops... something went wrong";

    });
});
```

here is the web.api tourController code to return data...

```
// GET api/Tour
public IQueryable<Tour> GetTours()
{
    return db.Tours;
}
```

here is how the data is returned when called api/tour in browser...

```
<Tour>
<Description>Majestic tour of the coast</Description>
<Id>1</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>3</Length>
<Name>Big Sur Retreat</Name>
<Price>750.00</Price>
<Rating>Medium</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Day trip hike</Description>
<Id>4</Id>
<IncludesMeals>false</IncludesMeals>
<Length>1</Length>
<Name>Channel Islands Excursion</Name>
<Price>150.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>
Challenging tour of the hottest place in North America
</Description>
<Id>5</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>2</Length>
<Name>Death Valley Survivor's Trek</Name>
<Price>250.00</Price>
<Rating>Difficult</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Majestic tour of the coast</Description>
<Id>6</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>3</Length>
<Name>MODIFIED Brand New Tour</Name>
<Price>750.00</Price>
<Rating>Medium</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>7</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>8</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>9</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>10</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>11</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>12</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>13</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>14</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>15</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>16</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>17</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>18</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>19</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
<Tour>
<Description>Created with HttpClient</Description>
<Id>20</Id>
<IncludesMeals>true</IncludesMeals>
<Length>10</Length>
<Name>.NET Client Tour</Name>
<Price>500.00</Price>
<Rating>Easy</Rating>
</Tour>
</ArrayOfTour>
```

Lastly...here is the response i get in chrome...

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Big Sur Retreat","Description":"Majestic tour of the coast","Length":3,"Price":750.00,"Rating":"Medium","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":4,"Name":"Channel Islands Excursion","Description":"Day trip hike","Length":1,"Price":150.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":false},{"Id":5,"Name":"Death Valley Survivor's Trek","Description":"Challenging tour of the hottest place in North America","Length":2,"Price":250.00,"Rating":"Difficult","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":6,"Name":"MODIFIED Brand New Tour","Description":"Majestic tour of the coast","Length":3,"Price":750.00,"Rating":"Medium","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":7,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":8,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":9,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":10,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":11,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":12,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":13,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":14,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true},{"Id":15,"Name":".NET Client Tour","Description":"Created with HttpClient","Length":10,"Price":500.00,"Rating":"Easy","IncludesMeals":true}]
```

Why is this Json not returning like XML data so that I can call (data.tour) in angular and play with the data on the webpage? Does it get pretty complicated here, or is there a simple way to do this? I guess I need for it to return similar to this to be clear...

```
{"tour": [{"Id":1,"Name":"Big Sur Retreat","Description":"Majestic tour of the coast","Length":3,"Price":750.00,"Rating":"Medium","IncludesMeals":true}]}
```

Now if it returns like this my code should work just fine.  any ideas?

Comment: Please just use indentation rather than a `<code>` HTML tag to format code - read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details. As for why the data is returned as JSON - I strongly suspect that the AJAX call includes an appropriate "accept" header to show that it's expecting JSON back. It's more conventional for web services to return JSON than XML when they're going to be consumed by AJAX, to be honest... is there any particular reason you want XML here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get it as XML, you are already getting a valid JSON, you can use it like this: see this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinaidoron/y8dn48wn/1/)

Just replace the data object with the one you are getting from the http call.

```
<div ng-controller="myCon">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="tours">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in tours">
                <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.Rating }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


angular.module('myApp',[]).controller("myCon", MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var data = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Big Sur Retreat",
        "Description": "Majestic tour of the coast",
        "Length": 3,
        "Price": 750,
        "Rating": "Medium",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Channel Islands Excursion",
        "Description": "Day trip hike",
        "Length": 1,
        "Price": 150,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": false
    },
    {
        "Id": 5,
        "Name": "Death Valley Survivor's Trek",
        "Description": "Challenging tour of the hottest place in North America",
        "Length": 2,
        "Price": 250,
        "Rating": "Difficult",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 6,
        "Name": "MODIFIED Brand New Tour",
        "Description": "Majestic tour of the coast",
        "Length": 3,
        "Price": 750,
        "Rating": "Medium",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 9,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 10,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 11,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 12,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 13,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 14,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 15,
        "Name": ".NET Client Tour",
        "Description": "Created with HttpClient",
        "Length": 10,
        "Price": 500,
        "Rating": "Easy",
        "IncludesMeals": true
    }
];
    $scope.tours = data;

}
```

Comment: you're answer was helpful. I guess my confusion came from also working with the angular.js asp.net GeekQuiz project on microsoft's website. I remember I was getting a callback that I was looking for. In that case it was returning a more complex object, but I still don't get why mine returns differently. It works as you say. I just changed data.Tour to data and then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy it works, please consider accepting the answer, thanks